# Strongly continuous semigroup

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Given the following PDE
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}u'(t)&=&A(u(t)) + f(t)\ \mathrm{for\ all}\ t \geq 0\ ,\\
u(0)&=&u_0\\\end{array}\right.$$

with $D(A) = H^2(0,1) \cap H_0^1((0,1))$

Now assume that $(T(t))_{t \ge 0 }$ is the strongly continuous semigroup generated by $A$, $u_0$ should be a $L^2$ function and $f$ a $L^2$ function.
Now my question is:

The solution to this PDE is given as

$$u(t) := T(t)u_0 + \int_0^t T(t-s)f(s)$$

Is this expression then continuous in time?

My idea is that the first term is continuous in time, as $T$ is strongly-continuous. Moreover, the integral is continuous and therefore I think it is very likely that also the second term is continuous in time, but somehow we need to justify that also the composition of the integral and the integrand is continuous. How can I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition works perfectly, let's write down the details.

> We need to prove that $u(t + h) - u(t) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Let's first assume that $h \to 0^+$:
\begin{align}
u(t + h) - u (t) = &\ \big(T(t + h) - T(t)\big)u_0 + \int_0^{t + h}T(t + h - s)f(s) - \int_0^tT(t - s)f(s) \\
= &\ T(t)\big(T(h)u_0 - u_0\big) + \int_0^t\big(T(t + h - s) - T(t - s)\big)f(s) + \int_t^{t + h}T(t + h - s)f(s) \\
= &\ T(t)\big(T(h)u_0 - u_0\big) + (T(h) - I)\Big(\int_0^tT(t - s)f(s)\Big) + \int_t^{t + h}T(t + h - s)f(s).
\end{align}

The first two terms tend to $0$ as $h \to 0$ since $T$ is strongly continuous (hence it approaches the identity operator as its argument goes to $0$). To deal with the last integral notice that $$\Big\|\int_t^{t + h}T(t + h - s)f(s)\Big\|\le M\int_t^{t + h}e^{\omega (t + h - s)}|f(s)| \to 0\ \text{as}\ h \to 0.$$

This concludes the proof for $t = 0$. If $t \neq 0$ we need to study the limit from the left. This case can be treated similarly, indeed let's consider $h \to 0^+$ and expand $u(t - h) - u(t)$ considering values of $h$ for which $t - h \ge 0$: 
\begin{align}
u(t - h) - u(t) = &\ \big(T(t - h) - T(t)\big)u_0 + \int_0^{t - h}T(t - h - s)f(s) - \int_0^tT(t - s)f(s) \\
= &\ T(t - h)\big(u_0 - T(h)u_0\big) + \int_0^{t - h}\big(T(t - h -s) - T(t - s)f(s)\big) + \int_{t - h}^tT(t -s)f(s) \\
\to &\ 0.
\end{align}

Comment: The first term goes to zero as $T(h) \rightarrow \operatorname{id}$ for $h \rightarrow 0$ in the strong topology, the same for the second term. In the third term, we have that the integrand can be bounded, as $T(t-s)$ can be bounded by some exponential and $f \in L^2,$ so i.e. in $L^1$ (since domain is bounded) and therefore we can just let the limit $h \rightarrow 0,$ as the integrand is well-behaved (of course then the integral is zero). Correct?

Comment: @user167575: you are correct.Please check my proof again since I have edited to include more details.